# jqueryui not rendering on sharepoint 2013 page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a 2013 sharepoint site I created a CEWP to read my hmtl page. All the html is rendering ok but I am having some trouble linking jqueryui.css or jqueryui.min.js into my site. It works ok when running the html locally.

Screenshots from SharePoint and Localhost respectively [image: Sharepoint]
[image: Localhost]

This is how I am calling the files

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All the code is working fine just can not make the call in SharePoint.

Any advice is greatly apperciated!

**EDIT:**
I ran with F12 debug and I did recieve the follow error "Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'"

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var faqAccordian;
var faqSubAccordian;

var faqNextButton;
var faqSearchInput;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
faqNextButton = $("#faq_btn_next");
faqSearchInput = $('#faq_search');
var faqAccordionInput = $("#faq_accordion");
var faqSubAccordionInput = $(".faq_subaccordion");

faqAccordian = faqAccordionInput.accordion({
heightStyle: "content",
collapsible: true,
active: false,
create: function(event, ui) {
  $('#faq_loading').hide();
  faqAccordionInput.show();
}
});
```

I get error here, however I believe this error is attributed to the jqueryui not loading, from researching the error.

**EDIT:**
Upon more research I believe the issue is Sharepoint makes its own Jquery call, so therefore my Jqueryui is loading up then sharepoint makes its own call to jquery and overwrites my jqueryui. I found a way on how to tell my script to wait ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyFunction, "sp.core.js"); but I dont believe I have the semantics correct on where to put the wait.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var faqAccordian;
var faqSubAccordian;

var faqNextButton;
var faqSearchInput;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(MyFunction, "sp.core.js");
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
faqNextButton = $("#faq_btn_next");
faqSearchInput = $('#faq_search');
var faqAccordionInput = $("#faq_accordion");
var faqSubAccordionInput = $(".faq_subaccordion");
..... rest of javascript continues here
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hfzsxp9b/5/

EDIT:
I need to get Jquery to load before Jqueryui [image: Network Load]

Comment: Try using absolute URL’s for your CSS files and the last js file, not relative paths.

Comment: Yeah tried that too, that was my first approach. I was hoping the relative path would help since the files were now stored in within shatepoint. Same results for both

Comment: Do you get any errors with the browser (f12) debugger?

Comment: yes, added error section into post

Comment: Also when using jQuery in SharePoint avoid using the dollar sign and type 'jQuery' instead. SharePoint is sometimes using the dollar in its own scripts.

Comment: On the surface it looks like jquery-ui is not loading. Are you storing it locally or are you getting it from a CDN?

Comment: it is stored from within my sharepoint library /Shared%20Documents/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the html call of the jquery-ui.min.js and I used a .getScript from within my javascript code to call the jqueryui.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
JQuery.getScript('jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js',function(){
faqNextButton = $("#faq_btn_next");
faqSearchInput = $('#faq_search');
var faqAccordionInput = $("#faq_accordion");
var faqSubAccordionInput = $(".faq_subaccordion");

faqAccordian = faqAccordionInput.accordion({
heightStyle: "content",
collapsible: true,
active: false,
create: function(event, ui) {
  $('#faq_loading').hide();
  faqAccordionInput.show();
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the page using SharePoint Designer or Notepad. Place the references directly into the page under `<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` tag.

For example:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://<filelink>" /> 
    <!-- other references-->      
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: No luck, I think I have another issue. I added the errors in the orginal post

Answer (score 0):

Disable Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) in sharepoint than try once with basic alert jquery & confirm.

Comment: basic jquery loads ok and MDS is already disabled